# Laravel check user role on function construct

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make the entire controller only available for admins, but when I try to access a normal user account, they can still access methods in the `AdminController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        if (!Auth::guest())
        {
            if (!$request->user()->hasRole('admin'))
            {
                return redirect('/');
            }
        } 

        else 
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.index');
    }
}
```

And here is the `User` model where it checks the roles:

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return null !== $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first();
    }
```

Comment: `Auth::` wont work in constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register middleware that does that for you in the constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('adminOnly');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am quite new to Laravel and I didn't know this. I will study this one.